# Conflicting type in C but no clear difference between lines

Tags: c

I am trying to run a model written by someone else. When running the make file, I get the following error regarding one of the fonctions:

```
ground_layer.c:4391:6: error: conflicting types for 'func_'
real func_(R_fp funk, real *x) 
     ^
ground_layer.c:4360:17: note: previous declaration is here
    extern real func_(U_fp, real *);
```

I feel like it must be a silly mistake, bu my C is really rusty at this point, and I just can't identify the error. I've tried removing all the differences: adding an `x` in the first definition, removing the `funk`, but those changes seem to only make things worse.

For info, I am on MacOSX 10.11. Here is the code from the definition till the end:

```
/* Local variables */
    static real a, b;
    static integer j;
    static real x;
    static integer it;
    static real del, tnm, sum, ddel;
    extern real func_(U_fp, real *); 

/* ********************************************************************** */
    b = exp(-(*aa));
    a = 0.f;
    if (*n == 1) {
    r__1 = (a + b) * .5f;
    *s = (b - a) * func_((U_fp)funk, &r__1);
    it = 1;
    } else {
    tnm = (real) it;
    del = (b - a) / (tnm * 3.f);
    ddel = del + del;
    x = a + del * .5f;
    sum = 0.f;
    i__1 = it;
    for (j = 1; j <= i__1; ++j) {
        sum += func_((U_fp)funk, &x);
        x += ddel;
        sum += func_((U_fp)funk, &x);
        x += del;
/* L11: */
    }
    *s = (*s + (b - a) * sum / tnm) / 3.f;
    it *= 3;
    }
    return 0;
} /* midexp_ */

/* ********************************************************************** */
/* ********************************************************************** */
real func_(R_fp funk, real *x) 
{
    /* System generated locals */
    real ret_val, r__1;

    /* Builtin functions */
    double log(doublereal);

/* ********************************************************************** */
    r__1 = -log(*x);
    ret_val = (*funk)(&r__1) / *x;
    return ret_val;
} /* func_ */
```

Comment: Take a look at 'extern real func_(...)'. Have you tried to remove this line?

Comment: @MartinEttl : if you look at the whole code that I posted, func_ is actually being used before the problematic line, so removing the initial declaration `extern real func_...` probably won't do much good, right?

Comment: what are U_fp and R_fp ?

Comment: tuple_cat has it. Explicitly, change `extern real func_(U_fp, real *);` into `real func_(R_fp, real *); ` Also, the `extern` isn't needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The declaration has `U_fp` but the definition has `R_fp`.

Comment: Ah! I knew it was silly. Somehow I didn't think that the actual parameter inside the definition mattered as long as the type was respected, but looks like I was wrong. Thanks for the superfast answer.

Comment: Since it's a bit of a stupid question in the end, should I just close/remove it or is there any value in leaving it out there?

Comment: @CynthiaGS I don't think you can delete it since it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: @user3386109: Oh ok, I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know!